# Notify android users of my website to install Android app from website?

Tags: javascript, android, web, google-play

I have a blog and created an Android app for that. I want my Android visitors to be notified about my app when they visit my website through an Android device.

A small fixed banner about the app would be great and clicking it should lead to play store market place.

Is there a drag and drop javascript solution available to do that?

Please help. Your input is appreciated.

Comment: After some search I found this solution, I'm giving it a try. https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner

Answer (score 0):

Use this JavaScript code on the website to detect if the visitor is visiting through an Android phone:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if( /Android|iPhone|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  var url=confirm("Would you like to download our mobile application?");
  if (url==true)
  {
    var url = window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    url.show(); 
  }
  else
  {

  }
}
</script>
```

Or this PHP code:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
    // Android Device
        // Here you me popup a dialog with a link to your google play page 
}
```